# eb create and eb deploy stuck on uploading 0%

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

I have installed eb cli using the two ways in the aws documentation. Both ways after installation, I have run `eb create` to create environment all steps go right and then it stuck on uploading [...] %0 and after couple of minutes if
`ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error`

I have created the environment on the web interface and on `eb deploy` i got the same scenario uploading %0 and after couple of minutes i got `ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error`

any ideas ?

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, eb deploy usually stucks at 0% with low network upload speed conditions (<1MBps).

Try using a different Internet connection.

Comment: My connection is 30MBps and stay still 0%

Comment: eb deploy start by creating a zip bundle of your code using git archive under .elasticbeanstalk/app_versions/<bundle_name>.zip, so please check if your user has permissions to write there. if you have permissions, try to create a bundle like eb deploy does use this oneliner: ' mkdir .elasticbeanstalk/app_versions; git archive --format zip -o .elasticbeanstalk/app_versions/test.zip HEAD;` if there are no errors, check your bundle size. AWS stats that bundle size cannot exceed 512MB - https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/applications-sourcebundle.html